# Add shadow to separate cell file in xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

I have separated `.xib` and `.swift` file for my tableView's cell. I'm trying to add some shadow around the cells, here is my code with shadow snipped added. This won't work, but I'm not sure how to implement this in another way

```swift
class ShopHistoryCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var shopName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var departureDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var arrivalDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var carClass: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rewardText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!

    var delegate: ShopHistoryCellProtocol?
    
    var recentShops: [ShopHistorySearch]? {
        didSet {
        }
    }
    private var shopViews: [ShopView]? = []
    
    //padding
    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += 20
            frame.size.width -= 2 * 20
            frame.origin.y += 10
            frame.size.height -= 2 * 10
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupShadow()
        
    }
    
    func setupShadow() {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        layer.shadowRadius = 4
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

And here is `.xib` file tree (cell)

[image: xib]

Answer (score 0):

To add a shadow effect to your custom UITableViewCell using a separate .xib and .swift file, you need to make sure that the shadow is applied to the correct layer. In this case, you can apply the shadow to the contentView of the cell.
Here's an updated version of your code that adds the shadow effect to the cell's contentView:

```
    func setupShadow() {
    contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    contentView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    contentView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
}
```

Also, the setupShadow() function is modified to apply the shadow properties to the contentView instead of the cell's main layer. Similarly, the updateShadowPath() function is called in the layoutSubviews() method to update the shadow path whenever the layout changes.

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    updateShadowPath()
}

    func updateShadowPath() {
    contentView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: contentView.bounds).cgPath
}
```